# Navigationcontroller - why isn't this working?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Why won't this work?

View1   loads View2.
In view2:

```
- (void) goToView {
  View3 *plainText = [[View3 alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"View3" bundle:nil];

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:plainText animated: NO];
       [plainText release]; 
  }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
         [self goToView]; 
         [super viewDidLoad];
  }
```

This will not trigger navigationController to pushView, but if I add a button and setAction (goToView), it works perfectly.  What kind of problem am I missing here?

Comment: This post does not belong in the community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your call to goToView in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad?

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(bool)animated {
    [super viewdidAppear:animated];
    [self goToView];
}
```

Comment: It a common mistake to use `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear:`. This causes problems because `viewDidLoad` is only called when a view is first loaded from nib. If you initialize a view it is never called and it is not called every time the view is used subsequently unless the view unloads from memory completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self goToView]; 
[super viewDidLoad];
```

try interchanging this 2 line.. i.e.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self goToView];
```

I am not sure...